# Magit status section with recent checkouts / visited branches?

Tags: magit, git

In the same fashion magit can offer the list of recent commits in a section of status buffer. I'd like to have a list of recent checkout/visited branches to be able to quickly switch to it (<kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>).

One of current patterns I have is :

- work on my topic branch
- find a bug unrelated to my topic
- switch to master and pull latest
- create a spinoff branch from master (checkout -b )
- fix bug
- push & pull-request
- go back to my topic branch

For last step I have to remember the name of my branch ; which is not handy for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented with this feature after digging through `magit` source code.

**TO ENABLE** it, as @tarsius, magit maintainer, points out in the comment below, use the function `magit-add-section-hook`.

add `exp-feat/magit-insert-recent-branches` to `magit-status-sections-hook` (preferably using `customize` interface since you would like to decide this section location in your `magit-status` buffer).

Here it goes (copied lots of stuffs from `magit` source code ):

```lisp
(defvar exp-feat/recent-branches (make-hash-table :test 'equal))

(defcustom exp-feat/recent-branches-limits 3
  "Limits" :type 'integer :risky t)

(defun exp-feat/magit-insert-recent-branches nil
  "Insert recent branches"
  (let* ((dir (magit-toplevel))
         (curr-branch (magit-get-current-branch))
         (prev-branch (magit-get-previous-branch))
         (rbs (--> (gethash dir exp-feat/recent-branches)
                   (nconc (list prev-branch curr-branch) it)
                   (-distinct it)
                   (-filter (lambda (a) (and a (not (equal a curr-branch)))) it))))
    (when rbs
      (when (> (length rbs) exp-feat/recent-branches-limits)
        (--> (1- exp-feat/recent-branches-limits)
             (nthcdr it rbs)
             (setcdr it nil)))
      (puthash dir rbs exp-feat/recent-branches)
      (magit-insert-section (rb "rb")
        (magit-insert-heading "Recent branches")
        (dolist (it-branch rbs)
          (let ((output (magit-rev-format "%h %s" it-branch)))
            (string-match "^\\([^ ]+\\) \\(.*\\)" output)
            (magit-bind-match-strings (commit summary) output
              (when (and t (equal summary ""))
                (setq summary "(no commit message)"))
              (magit-insert-section (branch it-branch)
                (insert (propertize commit
                                    'font-lock-face 'magit-hash) ?\s)
                (insert (propertize it-branch
                                    'font-lock-face 'magit-branch-local) ?\s)
                (insert (funcall magit-log-format-message-function
                                 it-branch summary) ?\n)))))))))
```

Comment: You should use `magit-add-section-hook` to add to a section hook. If you use Custom then you deprive yourself of any future changes to the default value.

Comment: @tarsius Edited. Thank you for pointing that out!